# Make a network (linked) of wordcloud with python, library?

Tags: python, graph, word-cloud

I would like to link one WORD to a classic wordcloud, and to link this WORD to another WORD2 and WORD2 is also linked to a wordcloud (like a network of wordcloud ), if someone know a library to do that in python or have a piece of code ?
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You can use [networkx](http://networkx.github.io), it has the huge amount of various graph processing algorithms. For example, your problem can be solved by this code (copy-paste it into your Jupyter notebook):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node('WORD')
G.add_node('WORD2')
G.add_edge('WORD', 'WORD2')
nx.draw(G)
```

[image]